# send different ID on click on every product

Tags: php

Im trying to have 3 different buttons which says order now and adds the selected product to the cart but now its always sending the same product to the cart.
The ?add= is always sending the same ID to the cart also if you press the order now button on the other products.

Original code:

```
    $itm = $adb->queryrow("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", array(intval($content['wlpid'])));
        $vat = $adb->querykeyvalues("SELECT id, multiplier FROM tax");
        $prijs = (($itm['price']*($vat[$itm['tax']]/100))/100);
    }
    echo '
    <div id="the_product_container" class="para_container"></div>
    <div id="anchor_1_product"></div>
    <div id="anchor_2_product"></div>
    <div id="anchor_3_product"></div>
    <div id="page_product" class="anchor_pos"></div>
    <div id="page_product_check" class="anchor_check"></div>

    <div class="bonds">
        <div class="scaleme">
            <img alt="Curolocker" class="content" src="/uploaded/overige/'.$content['main'].'">';
            $ar = array(
                1=>"point_one",
                2=>"point_two",
                3=>"point_tree",
                4=>"point_four",
                5=>"point_five",
            );
            for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
            {
                if(!empty($content['info'.$i]))
                    echo '<img alt="Product point" id="'.$ar[$i].'" class="'.$ar[$i].'" src="/uploaded/overige/'.$content['info'.$i].'">';
            }

        echo '</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobiel_text_con">';
        for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
        {
            if(!empty($content['info'.$i]))
                echo '<div class="text_block">
                    <h3>'.$content['info'.$i.'h'].'</h3>
                    <hr />
                    <p>
                        '.$content['info'.$i.'t'].'
                    </p>
                </div>';
        }
    echo '</div>
    <div class="pricetag">
      <p>'.number_format($prijs,2,',','.').' &euro;</p>
    </div>';

    if(!empty($content['wlpid']))
    {
        echo '<div class="button_holder_ordernow">
        <a title="Order Now" href="/winkelwagen.html?add='.$itm['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
        </div>';
    }
```

What i tried to do is this:

```
$subs = $adb->queryarray("SELECT *, (SELECT value FROM propertyvarchar WHERE lang=1 AND propid=1 AND product=p.id lIMIT 1) as name, (SELECT value FROM propertyvarchar WHERE lang=1 AND propid=5 AND product=p.id lIMIT 1) as opt FROM products p WHERE master=?", array($itm['id']));
if(empty($subs))
{
    echo '<div class="pricetag">
      <p>'.number_format($prijs,2,',','.').' &euro;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button_holder_ordernow">
        <a title="Order Now" href="/winkelwagen.html?add='.$itm['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
    </div>
    <div class="photo_overlay_filter2"></div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; width:100%;">
        <div class="pricetag">
          <p>'.$itm['name'].' ('.$itm['opt'].') '.number_format($prijs,2,',','.').' &euro;</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <div class="button_holder_ordernow" style=" padding-bottom:20px;">
                <a title="Order Now" href="/winkelwagen.html?add='.$itm['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo_overlay_filter2"></div>';
    foreach($subs as $s)
    {
        $prijs = (($s['fromprice']*($vat[$s['tax']]/100))/100);
        echo '<div style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; width:100%;">
            <div class="pricetag">
              <p>'.$itm['name'].' ('.$s['opt'].') '.number_format($prijs,2,',','.').' &euro;</p>
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;">

                <div class="button_holder_ordernow" style=" padding-bottom:20px;">
                    <a title="Order Now" href="/winkelwagen.html?add='.$s['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="photo_overlay_filter2"></div>';
    }
    echo '<br /><br /><br /><br />';
}
```

Comment: From the code you show you only ever select ONE product so `$itm['id']` can only ever be one number

Comment: Plus we have NO IDEA what `$subs` is

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry about that  added subs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.use diffrent urls for different actions, for example:

```
<div class="button_holder_ordernow" style=" padding-bottom:20px;">
    <a title="Order Now" href="/ORDERNOW.html?add='.$s['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
</div>
<div class="button_holder_addtocart" style=" padding-bottom:20px;">
    <a title="Order Now" href="/ADDTOCART.html?add='.$s['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">add to cart</a>
</div>
```

2. your `SELECT` statment is limited to one only record, try this insead:

```
SELECT * FROM products
```

or even better (query preformance and "code-readable" reasons)

```
SELECT 
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4
FROM
    products
```

this case you got **ALL** products, you can limit it or paginate results by `LIMIT` parameter and simple trick - add to url `&page = XXX` and in php do something like this:

```
$page=0;
$articles_per_page = 10;
if (isset($_GET['page'] && (int)$_GET['page']>0) {
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}
$limit = 'LIMIT ' . $page * $articles_per_page . ', ' . $articles_per_page;

$sql= "SELECT 
        field1,
        field2,
        field3,
        field4
    FROM
        products
    {$limit};";
```

ofcourse you have to add at least links to prev ( `$page - 1` ) and next ( `$page +1` ) pages or count pages via additional query (use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products` and divide result via $articles_per_page) and create links to result pages.

additional: if you wish to show only one article use `WHERE article_id = %d` and not `LIMIT 1`.

ONE MORE THING:
if you have array of desired article_id use :

```
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4
FROM products
WHERE article_id IN ( **ID_LIST** );",
```

where **ID_LIST** is comma separated id list-just `implode(',', $ids_array)`

Answer (score 0):

To select all products you could change your SQL query to:
`SELECT * FROM products`
When you should add some foreach to iterate each product.

Answer (score 0):

Your Products Query has Limit = 1, and you're loading your item's Id from it, why would the id sent be different?